# laravel queue use connection object provided

Tags: laravel, redis, queue, swoole

I need to dispatch a job from a swoole coroutine environment.
if I directly use the default redis connection. an error will be thrown

```
Uncaught Swoole\Error: Socket#17 has already been bound to another coroutine#81, reading of the same socket in coroutine#80 at the same time is not allowed
```

I think this should be caused by the redis connection.

so I want the dispatcher uses a connection pulled from a connection pool to dispatch the job.

How could I apply my redis connection object to the dispatcher?

Comment: I solve this problem by replacing the laravel job with swoole task.
And disable coroutine for the task worker. Then the task can use laravel code as usual now.